# Why git clone fails for some repository names?

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

I just migrated with `git-lfs` a clone of my existing repository from the local directory `/mnt/1TB/DataWin_to_sync/GITRepoWin/ubuntu18-config.git` but without pushing (the push failed in fact).

Then I created a new git repository in another directory (`/home/adr/GITRepoUbuntu/ubuntu18-config.git`) and tried to clone it:

```sh
git clone https://adrhc.go.ro/ubuntu18-config.git
Cloning into 'ubuntu18-config'...
fatal: repository 'https://adrhc.go.ro/ubuntu18-config.git/' not found
```

All directories in `/home/adr/GITRepoUbuntu` are exposed to `https://adrhc.go.ro/<<directory>>.git` by using gitweb + nginx.

But when I created the new git repository `/home/adr/GITRepoUbuntu/xubuntu18-config.git` and clone it:

```sh
git clone https://adrhc.go.ro/xubuntu18-config.git
Cloning into 'xubuntu18-config'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

My nginx logs this:

```
2020/09/28 13:38:11 [error] 26114#0: *120 open() "/fast-disk/apache-htdocs/ubuntu_packages/info/refs" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: adrhc.go.ro, request: "GET /ubuntu_packages/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1", host: "adrhc.go.ro"
```

Both `find /mnt/1TB/DataWin_to_sync/GITRepoWin -name ubuntu_packages` and `locate ubuntu_packages/info/refs` finds nothing on my HDDs.

Same fail I have for names:

- ubuntu16-config
- ubuntu10-config
- ubuntu0-config
- ubuntuNN-config

but no error (when cloning) for the names:

- uubuntu18-config
- uubuntu0-config
- uubuntu0
- uubuntuNN-config
- uubuntuNN

What is the issue and how should I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue; is a rewrite in my nginx configuration:

```
nginx_rewrites.conf:31:rewrite  ^/ubuntu[^/]*(/.*)?$        /ubuntu_packages$1          permanent
```